# Pass parameters from hidden field to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am new to AngularJS so i need a little help.

I have two hidden input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_type" value="news">
<input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="24">
```

I need to pass the values to the AngularJS Factory:

```
angular.module('commentService', [])

.factory('Comment', function($http) {

return {
    // get all the comments
    get : function(page_type, page_id) {
        return $http.get('/api/comments/index/'+page_type+'/'+page_id);
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Suspect you tool a wrong turn somewhere. Why do you have hidden fields in the first place in an angular template? Typically your view is dependent on your data model, not the other way around

Comment: I want to show the comments from some page. In the example is a page from type News with id 24. It is not necessarily to be an hidden field, but i need to pass somehow those params. Do u have better idea ?

Comment: Normally you would get data needed for the app from your back end api using `$http` or `$resource`  and your html templates would be static. Are you using a server side framework to generate this html?

Comment: yes, i am using php to pass these parameters. How can i do that. Can u give some code hint ?

Comment: Are you using an angular router so you can access url parameters within your app? That would probably be most common approach. Then depending on router used you access it's route parameters and pass those to your factory `get()` method

Comment: unfortunately this is the first time i use AngularJS and i am not familiar with the terms. What is angular router ?

Comment: Should find numerous tutorials but simplst one i know to look for off top of head is one on angular docs site. This link explains routing within their tutorial. It is the foundation of a single page app. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Thanks, but is it a simple the solution or not. I just need that to be done fast and cannot read the whole angular documentation

Comment: Well it is the foundation of a single page app. Up to you but generally pointless to build angular app without a router and you apparently already have use case for it